# Python Django: ImportError: cannot import name '...' from partially initialized module '...' (most likely due to a circular import) (......)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, windows

In a Django project, I need to import class-A from file-1 in file-2. and import class-B from file-2 in file-1.

These classes have their unique methods, and I want to use these methods within another file (like description above).

##### I'm working with:

> Python 3.8.10 (within a virtual environment)
>
> Windows 10 - 64 bit (latest build)
>
> Django 4.0.4

When I run`python manage.py runserver`, I see errors below:

```
(my_ea_proj) PS F:\my_ea_proj\ea_proj> python.exe .\manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\manage.py", line 30, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\manage.py", line 13, in main
    django.setup()
  File "F:\my_ea_proj\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "F:\my_ea_proj\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "F:\my_ea_proj\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 304, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "F:\my_ea_proj\ea_proj\ea_app\models.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .login_request_based import full_request
  File "F:\my_ea_proj\ea_proj\ea_app\login_request_based.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ea_app.all_utils.ea_utils import ea_utils_class
  File "F:\my_ea_proj\ea_proj\ea_app\all_utils\ea_utils.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ea_app.login_request_based import full_request
ImportError: cannot import name 'full_request' from partially initialized module 'ea_app.login_request_based' (most likely due to a circular import) (F:\my_ea_proj\ea_proj\ea_app\login_request_based.py)
```

```
F:\my_ea_proj\ea_proj>tree /F
F:.
│   manage.py
│   __init__.py
│
├───ea_app
│   │   admin.py
│   │   apps.py
│   │   login_request_based.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   tasks.py
│   │   tests.py
│   │   urls.py
│   │   views.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───all_utils
│   │       ea_remote_db.py
│   │       ea_utils.py
│   │       __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───migrations
│   │       __init__.py
│   |       ...skipped other migration files...
│
└───ea_proj
        asgi.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
        __init__.py
```

When I add below classes in `ea_utils.py` and `login_request_based.py` files, I got error `ImportError: cannot import name 'full_request' from partially initialized module 'ea_app.login_request_based' (most likely due to a circular import)...`**.** But when I comment-out one of them, problem fixed and built-in web server is launched successfully.

```
F:\my_ea_proj\ea_proj\ea_app\all_utils\ea_utils.py:
from ea_app.login_request_based import full_request

F:\my_ea_proj\ea_proj\ea_app\login_request_based.py
from ea_app.all_utils.ea_utils import ea_utils_class
```

How to fix this issue?.

**Thank you @mohamed-beltagy. but your comment/link didn't fix my problem. Please read note below.**

[What happens when using mutual or circular (cyclic) imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/what-happens-when-using-mutual-or-circular-cyclic-imports-in-python)

> If you do import foo (inside bar.py) and import bar (inside foo.py),
> it will work fine. By the time anything actually runs, both modules
> will be fully loaded and will have references to each other.
>
> The problem is when instead you do from foo import abc (inside bar.py)
> and from bar import xyz (inside foo.py). Because now each module
> requires the other module to already be imported (so that the name we
> are importing exists) before it can be imported.

> **Note**, if you do from foo import * and from bar import *, everything
> executed in the foo is in the initializing phase of bar, and the
> actual functions in bar has not yet been defined...

Comment: This is a circular import so I advise you to import only the code when you need it

Comment: @mohamed-beltagy, Unfortunetly I need 4~6 methods of both classes within both files.

Comment: can you share to files please

Comment: @mohamed-beltagy, both python files have more than 1000 lines. have you a solution to import and use !??? what about moving files to another directory has positive impact (i confused...... :/....)?

Comment: you can try to move file to another directory, it can be work also

Comment: can you check this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/what-happens-when-using-mutual-or-circular-cyclic-imports-in-python

Comment: You should share a minimal form of the code in both files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know my new solution is a trick or is a principle of Python in Django framework.

- Django==4.0.X  or  3.2.X
- Python=3.8.10
- windows==10 x64 (latest build)

Pleas look carefully to the output of the my command in question (**`F:\my_ea_proj\ea_proj>tree /F`**). and read my question carefully.

When i add the `from ea_app.models import BotReport` in file `ea_utils.py`, within main python block (next to the lines are related to the `import ...` or `from ... import ...`), I got error below:

> .....skipped.....
> File "F:\my_ea_proj\ea_proj\ea_app\all_utils\ea_utils.py", line 50, in module
> from ea_app.models import BotReport ImportError: cannot import name   'BotReport' from partially initialized module 'ea_app.models'
> (most likely due to a circular import)
> (F:\my_ea_proj\ea_proj\ea_app\models.py)

but when i add the `from ea_app.models import BotReport` in method's section of class(es), everything works fine without any problem. for example:

```
class EA_UTILS_CLASS (object):
    def get_transfers (self,  bot_id: int):
        from ea_app.models import BotReport
        ....skipped....
        ....skipped....
        tmpObj = BotReport.objects.get (id=bot_id)
        tmpObj.transfer.create(.........)
```

I hope my solution help to others Django+Python developers.

Have great times ;X

Answer (score 5):

If in one of the modules you import a model only to make a relation to it, e.g.:

```py
from characters.models import Character

class Inventory(models.Model):
    character = models.OneToOneField(Character, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='inventory')
```

You can do this and so remove the `import` at the beginning:

```py
#from characters.models import Character  # Becomes useless

class Inventory(models.Model):
    character = models.OneToOneField('characters.Character', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='inventory')
```

Comment: thanks you. but those are python files and not related to Django Models (those extra functions are used in Django model/admin/view files. for short time, I redefined all functions in a python class. but i want to have them in separated files.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with the following file structure:

```
├───models
│   │   app_1.py
│   │   __init__.py # (will refer to this as models.init)
│   │
│   ├───engines
│   │       app_2.py
│   │       __init__.py
```

So, in `models.init` i had a instance from `app_2` like this

```
from models.engines.app_2 import app2_class
new_app = app2_class()
new_app.do_something()
```

In my `app_1` module i had these imports:

```
from models import new_app
```

In my `app_2` module i had these imports:

```
from models.app_1 import app1_class
```

I tried several workarounds but none worked for me, but i was able to get rid of the error and get all classes and the instance in `models.init` to work properly.
This is the final solution i got around.
No change in `models.init` as i need to access it.
No change in `app_2` also.

In my `app_1` module i modified to this:

```
import models

    # Somewhere in the code, I went with
    models.new_app.do_something_different()
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: dear @n1klaus, i will check your solution and inform you. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem, ironically, I separated the classes I needed to import into a separate models file (models_3.py), and importing from there worked for me, I still don't know why this happens, because I have other models. they work this way, but there seem to be specific cases.

Old structure:

```
├───app
│   │   models_1.py
│   ├   models_2.py
│   │   __init__.py
```

new structure:

```
├───app
│   │   models_1.py
│   ├   models_2.py
│   ├   models_3.py
│   │   __init__.py
```

Comment: dear @luisferchxs, i will check your solution and inform you. Thanks you.